# How to add new class form-control input field to billing address section in magento 2.4

Tags: checkout, magento2.4, billing-address, class

How to add new class form-control input field to billing address section in magento2.4

Comment: You may do it in \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor::process

Answer (score 0):

Extend from module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/biling-address.html or module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/ into your extend theme in Magento_Checkout/web/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/biling-address.html Magento_Checkout/web/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/ and add there